# ERROR gl_surface_egl.cc(263)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE

Tags: android

If i run my android app in real device through android studio i got the below error message

```
 E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(263)] eglChooseConfig failed with
 error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
```

does any one faced this issue ? what is the exact reason for this ? please help me.
Thanks